# Find, xargs and grep combination throws an error

Tags: grep, aix, xargs

The command which throws the error:

```
$ find /mydir/tmp/*20151014* -print | xargs grep -l 'filesTransmitted=1'
bash: /usr/bin/find: The parameter or environment lists are too long.
```

Is there any optimal command for doing the same?

Comment: Just try `find '/mydir/tmp/*20151014*' -type f -exec grep -l 'filesTransmitted=1' {} \;`

Comment: @heemayl no luck. Getting same error:

find  /mydir/tmp/*20151014*  -type f -exec grep -l 'filesTransmitted=1' {}

bash: /usr/bin/find: The parameter or environment lists are too long.

Answer (score 4):

It's the expansion of the file (directory?) names in `/mydir/tmp/*20151014*` that's the problem here.

Try this instead, which avoids the need for your shell to expand the wildcarded name into a list:

```
find /mydir/tmp -name '*20151014*' -exec grep -l 'filesTransmitted=1' {} \;
```

It's slightly different to yours, in that yours searches files, or all files in directories, starting from matches to `/mydir/tmp/*20151014*` whereas mine searches all files whose name matches `*20151014*` anywhere under `/mydir/tmp` . If this doesn't meet your requirements please provide a *sample* set of the files and their directory paths.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the issue; just a note that if this workaround can't be made to work *and* the number of arguments would fit in 4096 Kb (4 Mb!), then `chdev -l sys0 -a ncargs=1024` would increase the argument-size limit to 1024 * 4 Kb blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your argument list is too long. Check this page :
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution

`getconf ARG_MAX` will give you the maximum size allowed for arguments.

Try changing the maximum stack value, with `ulimit -s` you display current value, and with `ulimit -s (value)` you change it. You can also use `ulimit -s unlimited`.

Reading all these articles, it seems that after linux kernel 2.6.32 the value of ARG_MAX is dynamically allocated and it is based on the ulimit -s value.

Comment: Except the Q is tagged AIX...

Comment: ooops yes i missed that

Comment: However my answer is valid for AIX too, actually more applicable as under AIX the `ncargs`attribute is not dynamic. See  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4329/gfxzh/index.html . The ARG_MAX attribute exists too. Here there are other solutions offered : http://aixsysadmin.blogspot.fr/2009/07/parameter-list-is-too-long.html

Comment: ARG_MAX is getconf's way to display ncargs